# Processing logs once. Based on date-time and thread name

Tags: java, parsing

I need to import logs to a data base. The logs are in text files of 4-5 MB each. And on another server. Get via http. New file appears when previous over 4mb, same url. The format includes full date-time stamp with milliseconds, thread name and other details.

I assumed that 2 logs of same thread wont have the same date-time, that there will atleast be a milliesecond of difference. I did this so I can guard against the same log file being processed twice. Reason for this is that logs are not local but we download them from a serer, over http. There is no api to know if got the same logs before.

Is there any way to know that a log is in fact unique?

Sample:

> 2018-01-06 16:25:09,516 DEBUG com.sel2in.Ap.App [thread-1] start
>
> 2018-01-06 16:25:09,521 WARN com.sel2in.Ap.App [thread-1] main null
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "v"
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "v"    at
> java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>
> ~[?:1.8.0_20]     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
>
> ~[?:1.8.0_20]     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
> ~[?:1.8.0_20]     at com.sel2in.Ap.App.main(App.java:18) [Ap-1.jar:?]
>
> 2014-11-06 16:25:09,522 DEBUG com.sel2in.Ap.App [thread-1] Process 4 txns